# Jensen's and Logarithm / Measure Theory

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I have this problem of measure theory dat says:

Let $(X,F,\mu)$ be a probability space and $f\in L^1 , f\geq 0$

Prove that

$\int_X \log f d\mu \leq \log (\int_X fd\mu)$

And prove that the equality holds if and only if $f$ is a constant function $f>0$ (estrictly).

The inequality comes out from the Jensen´s inequality, and if $f$ is a positive constant, is easy to prove that de equality holds. My problem is the other side of the equivalence (if the equality holds, then $f$ is a constant. Could you give some help/ hints?

Answer (score 4):

Write $m:=\int f\,d\mu$. Since the log function is strictly concave, there exists a linear function $h:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ (i.e., a straight line) such that
$$
h(x)\ge\log(x)\;\mbox{for all $x$}\tag1
$$
with the property that $$h(x) = \log(x)\;\mbox{ if and only if}\; x=m.\tag2$$

Now suppose $\int\log f\,d\mu = \log\int f\,d\mu$. Then
$$
0 = \log\left(\int f\,d\mu\right) -\int \log f\,d\mu \stackrel{(2)}= h\left(\int f\,d\mu\right) - \int\log f\,d\mu\stackrel{(*)}=\int[h(f)-\log f]\,d\mu
$$
(note that (*) uses the fact that $h$ is linear.) But by (1), the integrand on the right is nonnegative, hence it must be zero a.e. if it integrates to zero. And by (2), we then conclude that $f(x)=m$ a.e.

Comment: Thanks, it´s really clear to me. Problem solved